# How to see which program using specified driver?

Tags: software-rec, drivers

How to see which program is using specified driver? For example I want to check which program is using a laptop's camera.

How can I see this?

Comment: Here is a good starting point: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Another good starting point would be telling us what platform you are on. Window, perhaps? Mac OS X? Linux?

Comment: do you receive an error "webcam being used by another application"? can you poste make and model of the camera and your OS?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Windows.  Seconded: try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).